# How to send email to group owner when team members post message in MS teams group/channel

Tags: microsoft-teams, powerapps, power-automate

I'm new to Power Automate. I have a group in Microsoft teams and inside that group there is a Channel "Leave".

Is there any ways, to send one automatic emails to the owners (group owners) each time someone post a message about their leave in the channel? Will Power Automate help here? Are any tutorials available for this?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a flow template specifically for your case

https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/galleries/public/templates/4289ec53edec430b8b760234bcc87267/send-an-email-when-a-new-message-is-added-in-microsoft-teams/